# Changing location of Postman's data directory

Tags: postman, appdata

My company has applied a max size limit on the Windows %APPDATA% folder.  I checked and found Postman is the largest user of the directory.  Is there anyway I can do to make Postman use a different data directory?  I have looked around the Postman UI, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about the data that Postman stores. But the app (every version) gets installed in the appdata folder.

[This Postman community post](https://community.getpostman.com/t/installation-directory-windows/217/4) tells what you probably noticed yourself: You can't install in another directory. But in the following thread, it was recently posted that you can just run the app after moving the folder from the appdata folder. I can confirm that. The Postman updater gets a bit confused the first time. It does appear to install new versions in whatever folder you moved the app to. I think you will have to update some shortcuts left and right to  make it work smoothly.